# How can I find the exact cause of systemd service unable to start (service has a bad unit file setting)?

Tags: systemd, systemd-service

This is really annoying that `systemd` only responded that my configuration of a service file is wrong, but does not specify where is wrong exactly:

`/lib/systemd/system/auto_pgha.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL High Availability
After=network.service
After=firewalld.service


[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/etc/repmgr
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'echo -e "\n"  `date +"%Y/%m/%d %a, %X"`": STARTING \n"  >> pgha.log'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "python3 pg_high_availability.py  &>> pgha.log"
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Inside directory `/etc/repmgr` the two commands worked just fine. But the systemd service just responded with an error:

```
# systemctl start auto_pgha
Failed to start auto_pgha.service: Unit auto_pgha.service has a bad unit file setting.
See system logs and 'systemctl status auto_pgha.service' for details.

# systemctl status -l auto_pgha
○ auto_pgha.service - PostgreSQL High Availability
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit auto_pgha.service has a bad unit file setting.)
......
auto_pgha.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be be started.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `systemd-analyze verify` command. If we put the content from your question into `pgha.service`, we see:

```
$ systemd-analyze verify pgha.service
.../pgha.service:10: Failed to resolve unit specifiers in echo -e "
"  `date +"%Y/%m/%d %a, %X"`": STARTING
"  >> pgha.log: Invalid slot
pgha.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
Unit pgha.service has a bad unit file setting.
```

You're getting this error because systemd itself uses `%<something>` tokens (see the ["Specifiers" section of the `systemd.unit(5)` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers).

You would need to write:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'echo -e "\n"  `date +"%%Y/%%m/%%d %%a, %%X"`": STARTING \n"  >> pgha.log'
```